# MonoTouch fails to open xib file when associated controller is derived from base class

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've created a UIViewController-derived base view controller which most of my controllers inherit:

```
public abstract class ViewModelViewController<T> :
  UIViewController where T : ViewModelBase
{
...
}
```

as soon as a controller derives from this base controller ...

```
public partial class MainViewController :
  ViewModelViewController<MainPageViewModel>
{
..
}
```

attempting to open the .xib associated with the controller results in this error which won't go away through rebuilding, restarting or whatever desperate measure:

```
Error updating Objective-C type information. Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: type.

ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Dom.Parser.ProjectDom+<GetInheritanceTree>c__Iterator33.MoveNext () [0x0023d] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Dom.Parser/ProjectDom.cs:164 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.ResolveCliToObjc (MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectTypeInfo type) [0x000fb] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectProjectInfo.cs:182 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update () [0x000fe] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectProjectInfo.cs:89 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update (Boolean force) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectProjectInfo.cs:66 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateTypes (IProgressMonitor monitor, Boolean force) [0x00034] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:302
```

The only workaround (which is not really not an option), is to comment out the entire partial class before editing the xib. This is a showstopper.

Does anyone know a real workaround?

Comment: Could you please update your code with the constructors of both the base and MainViewController are you using?

Comment: Please full a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com Product: **MonoDeveloper** Component **iPhone Add-in**. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for [this bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1706) will be in the next MonoDevelop update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In the meantime decorating my base controller with [Register("ViewModelViewController")] seems to mitigate the problem.